# Exception on push_back to vector in method of class exposed to DLL

Tags: c++, exception, dll, stdvector

I've created a DLL library, then linked it in a different project, compiled with different VS.

There's just a simple class exposed to DLL with `__declspec(dllexport)` like this:

```cpp
class TFLIBRARY_API MyClass
```

One of the fields of this class is a `std::vector<std::string>`, and part of the initialization of this class is filling that vector with data:

```cpp
std::string model(parsedLine[0]);
m_blocksModels.push_back(model);
```

This results in an Exception that I cannot understand:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.

I'm attaching a screen of the call stack.

Does it mean, that `std::vector` cannot be used like this in a library? Then what are my options?

Or, maybe there's a different problem? Please help me find it.

[image]

EDIT:
As suggested, I'm attaching a minimal example:
Class itself:

```
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)  
#endif  // LIBRARY_EXPORTS


class LIBRARY_API MyClass
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
    // to hide in .h file some fields, that have undefined class (from perspective of usage of DLL)
    std::unique_ptr<Model> m_model;
    std::vector<std::string> m_blocksModels;
#endif  // LIBRARY_EXPORTS

public:

    bool Initialize(int& numberOfFrames, int& numberOfBlocks, const char* cgPath  = "model.pb");
}
```

Initialize definition:

```
bool MyClass::Initialize(int& numberOfFrames, int& numberOfBlocks, const char* modelPath )
{
    std::string cgPath{ modelPath };
    cgPath  = cgPath.substr(0, cgPath.find_last_of('.')) + ".cfg";
    std::ifstream file(cgPath);
    if (!file.good())
        return false;

    std::string line;

    // First line is: <number of frames>;<number of blocks>
    std::getline(file, line);
    std::vector<std::string> parsedLine = utils::parseLine(line);
    m_numberOfFrames = std::stoi(parsedLine[0]);
    m_numberOfBlocks = std::stoi(parsedLine[1]);;

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        parsedLine = utils::parseLine(line);
        std::string model(parsedLine[0]);
        m_blocksModels.push_back(model);
    }
    file.close();

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
#include "TFLibrary.h"

obj = MyClass()
obj.Initialize()
```

So I do not use field that is a vectr directly, it all happens inside of Initialize function

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are creating and using the class at runtime.  Note however that you can't safely use class objects across the DLL boundary, especially when different compilers are involved. If you are trying to declare the `vector` on the DLL side and access it on the EXE side, that won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example, deleted ost of code but I guess that every part that might be problematic is there. 
I do not directly modify this vector, it is modified by method of class from dll, only declaration of this part is visible for place where class is used. Declaration of fields is not even visible. I'm using only standard C arrays and pointer as parameters and returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a general failure of memory management in my code.